# How to shared memory with parent and child processes in c

Tags: c, linux, fork, shared-memory

I want to calculate the factorial with Shared memory and `fork()`parent and child processes.My problem is child process doesn't seems to work, I want to give a number from parent to child and after the child passes the result of factorial to the parent. But the result is same with the number I gave.

I was asked to use `snprintf()` or`spritnf()`or `itoa()` and `atoi()` in order to pass the variable to each process.

I reached the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>




int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int  shmid,fid,status,x;
    char *shm;
    char *s;
    int   i,y,c;

    key_t key=1990;
    //create shared memory
    shmid=shmget(1990,300,IPC_CREAT|0666);
    fid=fork();
    shm=shmat(shmid,NULL,0);

    if(fid>0)//parent process
    {   
        wait(&status);
        s=shm;
        printf("enter a number:");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        sprintf(s,"%d",x);//convert int to string
        printf("factorial of number:%d is:%s\n",x,s);//result
        shmdt(shm);
        shmctl(shmid,IPC_RMID,0);

    }else if(fid==0)//child process
    {   
        shm=shmat(shmid,NULL,0);
         c=atoi(s);//conver string to int
         // calculate factorial
         for(i=1;i<=c;i++)
         {  
            y *=i;
         }
         return y;
        sprintf(s,"%d",y);
        shmdt(shm);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The parent does not wait for the child to be done with the calculation.

Comment: `s` doesn't point to the shared memory in the child.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
if(fid>0)//parent process
{   
    wait(&status);
```

The first thing the parent process does is wait for the child to die.  Only then does it ask for the number that should be the input to the calculation.  This isn't going to work well.

You need the parent to ask for the number, write it into shared memory, and tell the child via some (other) IPC mechanism that the number is ready.  The child should then wake up, read the number, do the calculation, and write the answer, then notify the parent it is done simply by exiting.  Meanwhile, the parent can now wait for the child to complete, and then reads the answer from the shared memory.

Were it my code, I'd do the `shmat()` before calling `fork()`.  As written, the child uses `shmat()` twice (once just after the `fork()`, once in the `else if (fid == 0)` code.  That's not orthodox.

It's odd to create the `key_t key = 1990;` and then not use it.  I don't see `status` and `x` being used either.

As a way of calculating factorials, this is preposterous.  As an exercise in IPC and inter-process synchronization, it is a nice simple example.

Remember, 32-bit integers can only store values up to 12! while 64-bit integers can only store values up to 20!, so it is usually sensible just to create a table of factorials — or just calculate them on the fly.  Or you need to use floating-point arithmetic; it takes a while to get out their range (somewhere less than 200!, IIRC).